# How to Check Current Fragment in an If Statment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I have a top menu bar which includes a save button. I would like the save button to only perform the save action if the user has navigated through all fragments and filled out the information required. In the instance they have not done this, I would like a Toast to be made asking the user to continue filling out and navigating through the fragments. So, my question is, how can I write an if statement within my button click to say,

```
`if currentFragment == lastFragment {
save
}
else {
Toast
}`
```